# view the git repository on remote linux server -> in Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, git, git-remote, gitk

Problem: Need to view Git history visually in windows, repository is on remote Linux server (Ubuntu).
Question: What are two easy ways to view the git repository on remote linux server -> in Windows?

I have initially tried mirroring the remote mirror, then viewing it locally - updating when needed, but I get an error when connecting,

```
git clone --mirror username@serveraddress.com:/home/username/projectfolder

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Again I'm on Windows using Git Bash, trying to clone a remote repo that's on Linux.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/msysgit/

Comment: I tried installing that and forgive me if I am wrong, but there doesn't seem to be a direct method for viewing a remote repository with the gui?

Comment: what protocol do you use? If you are using https/git/ssl then you need a key to clone the repo.

Comment: git clone --mirror username@serveraddress.com:/home/username/projectfolder

Comment: Your URL doesn't look familiar to me, though that depends on the protocol you are trying to use to clone the repo. See the [GIT URLs section of the git clone man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html#URLS) for some examples. The question still remains: are you trying to use the http, https, ssh, or git protocol to receive the data?

Comment: @MikeSep that's an SSH url.

Comment: Honestly I didn't know how to answer that question, I had assumed it was git or ssh.

Answer (score 0):

There is no importance where the repo resides.

As the error said,
1- make sure you have the address right

2- make sure you have access to the address

Comment: I have access to the address, but I'm not creating a connection already - do I need to ssh before running the command?  If yes - won't that simply clone the repo to the server I ssh'ed to (instead of my local machine)? Thanks for the response.